# Problem to get a connectionString for CosmosDB in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cli

I am following the example:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/java-functions-eventhub-cosmosdb

But when I try to get the connectionString using Azure CLI, I receive the following error:

```
COSMOS_DB_CONNECTION_STRING=$( \
    az cosmosdb keys list \
        --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP \
        --name $COSMOS_DB_ACCOUNT \
        --type connection-strings \
        --query connectionStrings[0].connectionString \
        --output tsv)
```

The error message from `az`:

```
no matches found: connectionStrings[0].connectionString
```

Any help?

Many thanks in advance

```
az --version
azure-cli                          2.2.0

command-modules-nspkg              2.0.3
core                               2.2.0
nspkg                              3.0.4
telemetry                          1.0.4

Extensions:
azure-cli-iot-ext                  0.8.9
application-insights               0.1.4

Python location '/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.2.0_1/libexec/bin/python'
Extensions directory '/Users/juan.brena/.azure/cliextensions'

Python (Darwin) 3.8.2 (default, Mar 11 2020, 00:29:50) 
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)]

Legal docs and information: aka.ms/AzureCliLegal



Your CLI is up-to-date.
```

Example to show the current connection strings:

```
az cosmosdb keys list \                              
  --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP \
  --name $COSMOS_DB_ACCOUNT \   
  --type connection-strings
```

output:

```
{
  "connectionStrings": [
    {
      "connectionString": "AccountEndpoint=xxx",
      "description": "Primary SQL Connection String"
    },
    {
      "connectionString": "AccountEndpoint=xxx",
      "description": "Secondary SQL Connection String"
    },
    {
      "connectionString": "AccountEndpoint=xxx",
      "description": "Primary Read-Only SQL Connection String"
    },
    {
      "connectionString": "AccountEndpoint=xxx",
      "description": "Secondary Read-Only SQL Connection String"
    }
  ]
}
```

The idea is to get the first connectionString:

```
{
  "connectionString": "AccountEndpoint=xxx",
  "description": "Primary SQL Connection String"
}
```

Comment: I was able to execute the command without any problem. Can you try running your command without `--query` parameter and see if you are getting any output? Try running the following command: `az cosmosdb keys list \
        --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP \
        --name $COSMOS_DB_ACCOUNT \
        --type connection-strings`

Comment: It is not working for me. Your command run fine, but the issue is with the query.

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the output? Obfuscate the account name/key obviously :). Also, what version of CLI are you using?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the details. It’s completely weird. I get the same output and query worked for me just fine.

Comment: I am totally agree with you but I didn´t do anything different in my Azure CLI installation but the processor for my query return that error. I will try to reinstall Azure CLI tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
RESOURCE_GROUP='myResourceGroup'
COSMOS_DB_ACCOUNT='my-cosmos-account'

COSMOS_DB_CONNECTION_STRING=$(az cosmosdb keys list \
        -g $RESOURCE_GROUP \
        -n $COSMOS_DB_ACCOUNT \
        --type connection-strings \
        --query connectionStrings[0].connectionString \
        --output tsv)

echo $COSMOS_DB_CONNECTION_STRING
```

Comment: COSMOS_DB_CONNECTION_STRING=$(az cosmosdb keys list \
    cmdsubst>         -g $RESOURCE_GROUP \
    cmdsubst>         -n  $COSMOS_DB_ACCOUNT \
    cmdsubst>         --type connection-strings \
    cmdsubst>         --query connectionStrings[0].connectionString \
    cmdsubst>         --output tsv)
    zsh: no matches found: connectionStrings[0].connectionString

Comment: Maybe it is something with the Azure CLI, in terms of any dependency?

Comment: hmm, not sure. I used CloudShell in Microsoft Terminal and it worked fine.

Comment: Hi Marc, as you say, you are testing with a different artifact. In my case, I am testing with Azure CLI but you are testing with CloudShell. In my opinion, exist a possible issue in Azure CLI for OSX with a dependency used to execute the query. The normal command usage goes fine but the query has something, in my humble opinion.

Comment: yeah not sure. Tried same thing in Ubuntu 18.04 and worked ok there too.

Comment: Yes, it is something weird. Sometimes, it is happen. :)

Comment: I have just tested using the Azure CLI Docker image and the behaviour is normal. Conclusion: I have an issue in my OSX. thanks for the support

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem within my ubuntu devcontainer and was able to solve it by wrapping the query in **single quotes**:

```
az cosmosdb keys list \
  --name $ACCOUNTNAME \
  --resource-group $RESOURCEGROUP \
  --type connection-strings \
  --query 'connectionStrings[0].connectionString' \
  --output tsv
```